# What is the role of the hypothesis of E being convex and bounded in Kirszbraun's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Here is a proof of Kirszbraun theorem for a case where E is bounded and convex :

- If we  assume that E  is a bounded convex set of R^n, then the proof of Kirszbraun's theorem becomes easy:
- We start by setting K = closure of E, which is a compact convex set.
- We extend f to K by uniformly continuous extension: for every point x ∈ K, we take a sequence (xn)n of points in E converging to x, and we define
  f°(x) = lim (n→∞)
  f(xn),
  demonstrating that the limit exists and does not depend on the sequence
  The function f° thus constructed is indeed L-Lipschitz.
- Finally, we introduce the orthogonal projection PK onto K and set
  F(x) := f°(PK(x)), ∀x ∈ R
  d
  .
  It is clear that F extends f, and furthermore, since PK is 1-Lipschitz, we see that F is L-Lipschitz."

-but i still have some unclear points about the proof:

- Where exactly did we utilize the assumption that E is bounded and convex?
- How do we prove the assertion that "the limit exists and does not depend on the sequence"?
- Can you provide further clarification on the final step of the proof?